# The problem of not defining the Map object

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a character class for a game, but when I try to do anything it doesn't work. It only happens when I try to assign when the page is fully loaded.

Under normal conditions, if I run it when the DOM content is loaded, it works, but if I wait this long, the game characters sometimes come up with images that are not loaded or are in the loading state. It distorts the correct image.

Class:

```js
class Skeleton {
    constructor(updateFunction) {
        this.Faces = new Map();
        this.LeftSides = new Map();
        this.RightSides = new Map();

        this.CurrentFace = null;
        this.CurrentLeftSide = null;
        this.CurrentRightSide = null;

        this.Update = updateFunction;
    }

    addFace(name, src) {
        console.log(this.Faces);
        if (this.Faces?.has(name)) {
            console.warn(`Face ${name} already exists`);
            return;
        }

        const FaceImage = new Image();
        FaceImage.src = src;

        this.Faces.set(name, FaceImage);
    }

    addLeftSide(name, src) {
        console.log(this.LeftSides);
        if (this.LeftSides?.has(name)) {
            console.warn(`Left side ${name} already exists`);
            return;
        }

        const LeftSideImage = new Image();
        LeftSideImage.src = src;

        this.LeftSides.set(name, LeftSideImage);
    }

    addRightSide(name, src) {
        console.log(this.RightSides);
        if (this.RightSides?.has(name)) {
            console.warn(`Right side ${name} already exists`);
            return;
        }

        const RightSideImage = new Image();
        RightSideImage.src = src;

        this.RightSides.set(name, RightSideImage);
    }

    setFace(name) {
        if (!this.Faces.has(name)) {
            console.warn(`Face ${name} does not exist`);
            return;
        }

        this.CurrentFace = this.Faces.get(name);

        this.Update(this);
    }

    setLeftSide(name) {
        if (!this.LeftSides.has(name)) {
            console.warn(`Left side ${name} does not exist`);
            return;
        }

        this.CurrentLeftSide = this.LeftSides.get(name);

        this.Update(this);
    }

    setRightSide(name) {
        if (this.RightSides.has(name)) {
            console.warn(`Right side ${name} does not exist`);
            return;
        }

        this.CurrentRightSide = this.RightSides.get(name);

        this.Update(this);
    }
}

class Character {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.PoseTypes = ['normal', 'side'];
        this.Pose = 'normal';
        this.Skeleton = new Skeleton(this.UpdateCharacter);
    }

    UpdateCharacter(ThisSkeleton) {
    }
}
```

Code:

```js
const Assets = '../../assets/';
const Images = `${Assets}images/`;
const CharacterImages = `${Images}images/`;
const CharacterImageDirectory = name => `${CharacterImages}${name}`;

const CharDirectory = CharacterImageDirectory('someone');

const CharachterNodes = {
    Someone: {
        addLeftSide: {
            'stand': `${CharDirectory}/1l.png`,
            'up': `${CharDirectory}/2l.png`,
        },
        addRightSide: {
            'stand': `${CharDirectory}/1r.png`,
            'up': `${CharDirectory}/2r.png`,
        },
        addFace: {
            'happy': `${CharDirectory}/a.png`,
        }
    },
};
Object.keys(CharachterNodes).forEach(character => {
        const CharacterNode = CharachterNodes[character];

        Object.keys(CharacterNode).forEach(node => {
            const Node = CharacterNode[node];

            Object.keys(Node).forEach(name => {
                const SelectedSkeleton = eval(character).Skeleton;
                const SelectedFunction = SelectedSkeleton[node];
                SelectedFunction(name, Node[name]);
            });
        });
    });
```

Error:

```bash
Cannot destructure property 'LeftSides' of 'this' as it is undefined.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use page `load` event instead of `domcontentloaded` event. The page `load` will fire after images have loaded.

From MSDN:

> The load event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets and images. This is in contrast to DOMContentLoaded, which is fired as soon as the page DOM has been loaded, without waiting for resources to finish loading.